# Programatically obtain list of events that have been activated by user in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, error-handling

I've been trying to find a way to obtain a list of all the user activated events so that if the application crashes it can provide a full list of all the events leading up to the crash, which would help find issues.

Is this possible without having to manually call something within every single event?

It would be a great help if I could get a list similar to the one Visual Studio provides.
[image]

Currently when the program crashes it calls a custom form to inform the user;

```
Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
Private Sub MYExHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
   ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Dim EX As Exception

    EX = e.ExceptionObject
           frm_MsgError.ErrorMsg = EX.StackTrace
    frm_MsgError.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub MYThreadHandler(ByVal sender As Object,
 ByVal e As Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
    frm_MsgError.ErrorMsg = e.Exception.StackTrace
    frm_MsgError.ShowDialog()
        End Sub

Private Sub frm_Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MYExHandler
         AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf MYThreadHandler
```

So it would be even better if I could obtain the list here as well.
Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case sadly is that what you want to do just does not work.

To understand why you have to know what a "event" is. A event is basically a nice looking syntax for 3 Functions and a [`EventHandlerList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist).

The 3 functions are:

- Add a handler to the hash set
- Remove a handler from the hash set
- Invoke all handlers inside the hash set with a specific parameter

There is nothing more to it. If you declare a event with the `Custom` keyword you are able to implement these functions yourself.

That means that there is no magical central storage for all the event handler or even any common function that is used by all events. Each event stands alone.

That being said, there is a way to get all the events of a single class/instance and attach to them. This can be done by calling the [`GetEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getevents) method of the type of the class. The list you get contains `EventDescriptor` objects that offer the [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.eventdescriptor) method you need to attach to the event.

While it is not possible to attach to all events in the entire .NET runtime, you are able to attach to the events of specific objects.

I hope that helps.